# custom made symbol not showing up in schematic

Tags: eaglecad

I was able to define footprints and symbol for a customized part.

I was looking forward to using it in my schematic.

But when I looked for my part (ATF33143), it did not show up. (2nd image)

I have obviously enabled the part given the green light.

I am not sure what I'm doing wrong here.

It does show up in PCB board though.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think you should tell EAGLE project to `Use` this library. You will find this option somwhere in the drop downs of the top menu, most probably in "Library". Then it will appear in the list of libraries available for project. Or you can just put your file into standard `lbr` directory, then EAGLE must automatically get it into the list (probably you will need to restart it).

Comment: As an alternative, one can also double-click the item in the control panel.

Answer (score 1):

You have made both **Symbol** and **Package**, but not a **[Device](https://www.autodesk.com/products/eagle/blog/library-basics-part-3-creating-first-device-autodesk-eagle/)** that links the Symbol to the Package.
The Device contains the mapping of the pins, and the various type of packages the symbol can be ordered in.